# How to edit .htaccess to change site's login url?

Tags: login, htaccess

How do I edit the .htaccess file to change my site's login url?
Example, my site is example.com and I want the login url to be at **example.com/banana** instead of the default **/wp-admin**

Last questions asked were like 2 or 3 years ago and it might not be 'compatible' with the latest version on Wordpress.

I can access my site through SSH. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Easy: just add this to your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^banana$ http://example.com/wp-login.php [NC,L]
```

Now `http://example.com/banana.php` is your login page.